# How to play an audio file on a specific soundcard output on OS X

Tags: audio, sound-card, osx-yosemite, osx-mavericks, node.js

I would like to play sound files Wav/Mp3 on a specified channel of a multichannel output on OSX.
Unfortunatley `afplay` does not allow me to specify its output on osx as `aplay` does on linux.

Looking for shell command or nodejs solution, ...

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found while trying several approaches, is to use sox.

```
#!/bin/bash

## soundcard info on osx
system_profiler SPAudioDataType

## example out on the first two channels of the 16 outs.
./sox test.wav -t coreaudio "Dante Virtual Soundcard" remix 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Sox can access CoreAudio directly, and allows specifying the soundcard, and the remix module allows to specify outputs.
However, I encountered a bug with this approach, while playback the audio is randomly switching channels.

To work around that bug and to have a better design, I create virtual soundcards with [A virtual soundcard loopback tool](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) and thus no need for the remix.

Comment: Turns out that Rouge Amoba loopback is also buggy. It causes coreaudiod to eat up 10x the resources it would normally need. Blackhole's implementation seems to be better in this regard.